# Delete N random objects Django orm

Tags: python, django, orm

How can I delete 100 randomly selected objects in Django?

Example:

```
Book.objects.all()[:100].delete()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't understand when this would be useful, but here's one way

```
import random
ids = random.sample(Book.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True), 100)
Book.objects.filter(pk__in=ids).delete()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a lot "real" data that I want to fake a little for a test database.

Comment: I had to add `list()` around the query to get this to work:

    `ids = random.sample(list(Book.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)), 100)`